# How can a tiny-sized gunslinger increase the base die when we use houserules that favor larger creatures?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, house-rules, creature-size, gunslinger

I plan to go dwarf gunslinger with dual revolvers.

So in our game, size class rules have the following changes,

- size classes scale closer to what an IRL human would 4' 1" is the highest end of tiny and small is 4' "2 to 5' 2". So dwarves are classed as tiny not small.
- there is no attribute change from size.
- the base die for both melee and ranged weapons still change by 1 step though we skip weird shenanigans like d3

  - ie a large dagger does 1d6, medium dagger does 1d4, small 1d2, and tiny a flat 1
  - This makes larger characters objectively better than smaller ones for martial classes and smaller characters objectively better for caster classes than larger ones.
- We are level 7 and I'm not willing to dip.
- pretty much everything on the SRD is allowed including 3pp, homebrew is allowed on a case by case basis.
- Dual-wielding 1 handed range weapons follow the same rules as normal dual wielding and benefits from two-weapon fighting.

**I want a way to raise the base die itself of guns** since I can raise tons of other factors through homebrewed feats, god bonuses, and bloodlines. All three are homebrewed stuff that would take way to much work to explain in detail. The gravity arrow and lead blades spells and the impact enchant are ways to increase die by 1 step. I could probably get impact on my guns. However, I want to find ways to make multiple ones stack.

Comment: This is effectively just asking "How do I do more melee damage?", which is far too broad. What elements of this situation do you have control over? Are you considering which class to take a level in? What kind of weapon to acquire? Are you considering revising the house rules?

Comment: I tried making it specify only base die since I can raise other factors with minimal effort.

Comment: So to be clear on this, you've settled on gunslinger with dual revolvers, and you only care about trying to increase the base damage die, and the only house rule that you have that affects the base damage die is that it steps down one die size for small creatures. Is that right?

Comment: @MarkWells Yes.

Comment: Also, your title says "tiny-sized" but in the question you say it's a dwarf. What's with that?

Comment: @MarkWells our size classes are different below 4' 2" is tiny, not small so dwarves are small. Being 3' 9" and 3' 7" for males and females respectively. Also, should I remove the rules not related to dice?

Comment: Yes, you should.

Comment: @MarkWells anything else I can do to remove those vtc?

Comment: There's no real need to. Edits at least help prevent new close votes which are the only way your question could get closed. The two already there will eventually go away with time if the close voters don't remove them themselves

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're looking for. You want to increase ranged damage die size... but you're using every splatbook and also homerules we don't know (and aren't applicable even though you are using applicable ones)... are normal rules about [stacking size increases](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9t3f) in effect? You talk about adding [Impact](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/impact/) which is non-light melee only... do all melee things apply?

Comment: Why aren't Dwarves at least Small (considering they're Medium despite being short in Core)?! They're wide and dense! Height isn't everything! (not really applicable but it bothers me a bit)

Comment: More seriously, this honestly sounds like you need to just ask your GM. I don't feel like anyone else has the expertise necessary to answer about your specific game with the amount of changes made to it.

Answer (score 1):

## Just use a bigger gun

It's a bad idea because of the accuracy penalties, but you can just use a bigger weapon.  The rules for firearms state:

> The size of a firearm never affects how many hands you need to use to shoot it.

This is errataed by FAQ to specifically ban *Medium* and *Small* characters from using too-large firearms.  You have been houseruled to be a tiny character.  This means you can dual-wield Colossal Maxim M1910s if you don't mind the -24/-28 you get on your attacks and can carry the ~3,360 pounds of their combined weight.

You can also use a 'bigger'-- that is, more damaging-- weapon.  There are several weapons in the Technology Guide that deal substantial amounts of damage even if Tiny, though obviously a larger weapon of the same type would still be superior.

Answer (score -1):

well if you consider that tiny gunslingers would practice with like size targets, you might deduce that they would better marksman with better precision since they are used to hitting smaller targets.